# Can charcoal be sold and where?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I tried to sell them, but not even Belethor (General Goods, Whiterun) wants them.

Where can I sell charcoal?

Answer (score 5):

There are actually two types of charcoal found in Skyrim. Only one appears to be sellable to merchants. From the [wiki](http://skyrim.gamepedia.com/Charcoal):

> There are two different sizes of charcoal, one which can be used at the Atronach Forge and one which can be sold to merchants.

The more common stick-looking charcoal cannot be sold:

> [image: stick charcoal]
>
> A piece of charcoal. Used to make a rubbing from Calcelmo's Falmer Rosetta Stone and also in three Atronach Forge Recipes.

However, the chunk of charcoal found commonly in the Dragonborn DLC is able to be sold, it seems:

> [image: chunk charcoal]
>
> A larger, heavier piece of charcoal, more commonly found in the Dragonborn DLC, though some examples appear in the original game.

The wiki doesn't specify which merchants buy this type of charcoal, but it seems implies that general merchants will buy it, at least.

Comment: Can we make the smaller pieces from a big one?